# Subsets of a topological space and isomorphisms $X\longrightarrow X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topological space, and fix a subset $U\subseteq X$. I would like to find a characterization of the class

$ 
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \Omega_{U} = \{V\subseteq X\ |\ V\cong U \text{ with the induced topology} \}
$

in terms of the isomorphisms $X\longrightarrow X$. In other words, I would like to find a subset $\text{Homeo}_{U}(X,X)\subseteq \text{Homeo}(X,X)$ such that there exists a one-to-one correspondence

$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Omega_{U} \longleftrightarrow \text{Homeo}_{U}(X,X)
$

As underlined with the notation hereby introduced, I would like this subset to depend on $U$ only. Is it possible? Any ideas? We can also require the subsets $U$ and $V\in \Omega_{U}$ to be open, but no further hypothesis on the topology of $X$ should be assumed.

Comment: Do you want the bijection to be 
$\varphi\in\text{Homeo}_U(X,X)\mapsto \varphi(U)$, or any bijection ? By the way, I would prefer the notation $\text{Homeo}(X,X)$ because $\text{Hom}(X,X)$ could be confused with the set of continuous maps from $X$ to $X$ (the morphisms from $X$ to $X$ in the category $\mathbf{Top})$, as $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ denotes, in category theory, the set of morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ in the given category.

Comment: Any bijection will do. You are right about the notation.

Comment: I don't understand why the notation $Homeo_U(X,X)$ is justified.  Why should $\Omega_U$ be parametrized by some set of automorphisms of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Take $X=\mathbb R$, $U=[0,1)\cup[2,3)$ and $V=[0,1) \cup (2,3]$. A homeomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ has to be a strictly monotonic continuous map, so if $\varphi$ is increasing, we have
$$\varphi(U) = [\varphi(0), \varphi(1)) \cup [\varphi(2),\varphi(3)),$$
which can't be $V$ since $V$ contains a left-open interval as a connected component. If $\varphi$ is decreasing we have
$$\varphi(U) = (\varphi(1), \varphi(0)] \cup (\varphi(3),\varphi(2)],$$
which also can't be $V$, since $V$ contains a right-open interval as a connected component.

However $U$ and $V$ are obviously homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb R$. Hence, the map $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(U)$ won't work.

If you are looking just for any bijection, you are really just asking wether there is a subset of $\operatorname{Homeo}(X,X)$ of cardinality $\left|\Omega_U\right|$. Which is again just asking wether $\left|\Omega_U\right| \le \left|\operatorname{Homeo}(X,X)\right|$ as cardinals.

Comment: I see your point, but I was hoping that some sort of parametrization could be found explicitly.

Comment: May I ask where this question originates? Since the naive approach $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(U)$ fails, I don't see any natural way to construct such a bijection.

Comment: To be honest, is just something that I was asking myself. I taught that the isomorphisms that define $\Omega_{U}$ could be somehow be used and extended to the whole space $X$, but the whole idea might very well be wrong

Comment: I think the second $1$ in the second formula should be a $2$ :-)

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, thanks!